# If possible, how to run a chromeOS app in ubuntu without virtualization?

Tags: chromeos

I have a chromeOS app with GUI I want to run in my linux PC.

I'm willing to use containers for this purpose, if needed.

If not possible, what prevents it?

Comment: Chrome OS applications are designed for the Chrome OS, not Ubuntu.  Unless you have a VM with ChromeOS on it, you will not be able to execute the applications built and designed for ChromeOS in Ubuntu directly.

Comment: @ThomasWard I thought the executables were both ELF because ChromeOS is a modified version of linux although didn't see to be modified to an extent that it uses a format other than ELF to execute programs.